# compare folders and copying non identical folders and files

Tags: cmd

i have two folders `folder1`
and `folder2`

folder1 has

```
file1
file2
folder3
folder4
```

and folder2 has

```
file1
file2
file3
folder3
folder5
```

here i want to copy everything thats not present in folder1 from folder2
in this case copy `file3` and `folder5` to `folder1`

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Do you want an exact copy of folder 2, onto folder 1?  Robocopy in mirror mode will do that too, only copying the different/missing files and removing those that don't exist in folder 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
xcopy /e /s /d "folder2" "folder1"
```